# R - how to do an XY plot with two datasets in same graph?

Tags: r

I have a quick R question (as I'm trying to learn how to use it). I'm trying to do a simple XY plot that will show data from 2 datasets (var1 and var2). I'm able to load all the data into variables with no problem, but I can only plot var1. When I try plotting Var2, I get "Error in xy.coords(x, y) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ".

Any thoughts on how I can fix this?

Here is what I'm doing:

```
#dataset 1

val1_time <- data.frame(time=c("04/09/15 04:52:30", "04/09/15 06:04:30", "04/09/15 07:14:24"))
val1 <- c(5.05, 0.29, 1.1)
val1_time$time <- strptime(val1_time$time,"%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S") 

#dataset 2

val2_time <- data.frame(time=c("04/09/15 12:00:00", "04/10/15 12:00:00", "04/11/15 12:00:00"))
val2  <- c(1.925294118, 0.4555, 0.42)
val2_time$time <- strptime(val2_time$time,"%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S") 


plot(val1_time,val1,col="blue", pch=18)

lines(val2_time,val2,col=“red”, pch=18)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of mistakes in your code. First, when dealing with time series, it is essential to use a package such as `zoo` (ideal for dates without time) or `xts` (for dates and time). It allows you to merge time series easily, calculate returns, lag a series... Mistake that was fixed: You don't need $time in val1_time

```
library(xts);library(zoo)
#dataset 1
val1_time <- data.frame(time=c("04/09/15 04:52:30", "04/09/15 06:04:30", "04/09/15 07:14:24"))
val1_time<- strptime(val1_time$time,"%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S")
val1 <- c(5.05, 0.29, 1.1)
val1_xts <-xts(val1,val1_time)

#dataset 2
val2_time <- data.frame(time=c("04/09/15 12:00:00", "04/10/15 12:00:00", "04/11/15 12:00:00"))
val2_time <- strptime(val2_time$time,"%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S")
val2  <- c(1.925294118, 0.4555, 0.42)
val2_xts <-xts(val2,val2_time)

all_xts <-merge(val1_xts,val2_xts)
plot.zoo(all_xts,col=c("blue","red"), plot.type="single")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Lapointe for the wonderful explanation. I super appreciate it!

Comment: One quick question: I'm trying to run xts but I keep getting the error" Error: could not find function "xts". I tried installing the package (using: install.packages("xts")) but I and I don't get any errors. Do you know what may be going on?

Comment: `library(xts)` after the install and every time you start R. Don't forget to upvote and accept the answer.

Comment: Ok...  am still having some problems. I'm running a very similar code (based on above) and all the datasets load just fine. When I try plotting them together using: plot.zoo(all_xts,col=c("blue","red"), lwd=c(1,4), plot.type="single"), I only see a single line (the one that is blue). But, if I do plot(val1_xts) or plot(val2_xts) the data for val1_xts and val2_xts look fine.  Hence, do I need to add other syntax in order to be able to see both lines on the same graph?

Comment: Did you merge val1_xts  and val2_xts into all_xts? This line in the code above: all_xts <-merge(val1_xts,val2_xts)

Comment: If you did, check what your all_xts looks like compared to the one above (you have to rerun everything)

Comment: (1) xts is not significantly used in this example and without xts (but still using zoo) it would still work: `val1_z <- zoo(val1,val1_time); val2_z <-zoo(val2,val2_time); all_z <-merge(val1_z,val2_z); plot(all_z, col = c("blue", "red"), plot.type = "single")`  (2) if the merge creates NAs then you may need `plot(na.approx(all_z), col = c("blue", "red"), plot.type = "single")`

Comment: Thank you guys for the explanation! I was able to make it work after quite a bit of fumbling around with it. I think it had to do with the order I entered the parameters. Also, very nice to know about the NA plotting, since I noticed that these were present in the data (used by R for filling in for missing data points). Thanks!